# what is causing my error and no output to be created?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following python/scrapy test code, just trying to see if I can get a value from the page

```
import scrapy
import requests
import funcs as fnc


 headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
 headers.update({ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'})

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "tests"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [

            'https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/p/strikeforce-nfl-seattle-seahawks-bowling-ball-18sfcusttlshwksbwstg/18sfcusttlshwksbwstg',
            'https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/p/select-womens-ultimate-team-handball-16sctwwmnshndblllota/16sctwwmnshndb',  #BROKEN LINK FOR TESTING
        ]
    for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)    

def parse(self, response):
    page = response.url.split("/")[-1]
    itemd = response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="app-container"]/pdp-product-container/pdp-in-stock-default/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/pdp-product-title/div/div/h1/text()').get()
    filenotfoundname = '%s_urls_notfound.txt' % itemd
    filefoundname = '%s_urls_found.txt' % itemd

    if page.status_code == 200:            
        fnc.getallelements(filefoundname,itemd,'div','class')
    elif response.status_code == 404:
        fnc.lognotfound(filenotfoundname,page)
```

When I run it with the Green arrow in spyder not gets created in my folder.
If I run it from the command prompt to run the spider it returns an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'funcs'
I have another spider in the same directory that calls that same import and that one runs, what did I do wrong setting up this one?

everything looks correct and the same, but this one above complains about the missing module.

Here is part of the other spider that works..

```
import scrapy 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import funcs as fnc


headers = requests.utils.default_headers() 
headers.update({ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}) 

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider): 
name = "tags" 

url = "https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/p/nike-mens-air-zoom-pegasus-36-running-shoes-19nikmzmpgss36gryrnn/19nikmzmpgss36gryrnn"; 
req = requests.get(url, headers) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser') 

if req.status_code == 200:
########################################
    fnc.getallelements('ul_tags.txt',soup,'ul','class')
elif req.status_code == 404:
    fnc.lognotfound('urls_notfound.txt',url)
```

Comment: can you post the code from the other spider? you have some indentation errors but im guessing that's from formatting in sof?

Comment: you might also check that the two spiders do not have the same names

Answer (score 0):

I´m not familiar with spyder, but could different virtualenvs be causing this?  Try starting an instance of python in all the places you tried running the script and try to import func directly:

```
my-computer:some-folder nanna$ python 
Python 2.7.16 (default, Dec  3 2019, 07:02:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import func
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named func
```

if you get different results, there are either different installations of python at work, or different virtualenvs.  You can see the version of python when you start the instance, so you could maybe exclude the possibility of multiple installations that way:

```
my-computer:some-folder nanna$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Dec  3 2019, 07:02:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
my-computer:some-folder nanna$ python3
Python 3.7.6 (default, Dec 30 2019, 19:38:28) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
Nannas-MacBook-Pro:ankapp nanna$
```

Comment: hopefully ill give that a try today. Ill post back my findings.